# non-interferring operator does not show its contents

Tags: java, java-stream

Would you please let me know the reason that the peek operator does not show the system.out.print?

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //try stream.of
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
     Stream<Integer> p = numbers
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x >= 5)
    .peek(x-> System.out.print("peek at: " + x));

     System.out.print("peek at: ");
}
```

Comment: Because peek is intermediate and not terminate operation. So you need to add some terminate operation. Read about the differences.

Comment: @Carcigenicate after the .peek i added .filter for the second time..but still .peek does not print any thing

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the JavaDoc of [Stream#peek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.
>
> **This is an intermediate operation.**

More information about this can be found [in the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) But for completeness' sake:

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. **Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.**

Comment: after the .peek i added .filter for the second time..but still .peek does not print any ting

Comment: @LetsamrIt [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) is also an intermediate operation. Streams aren't traversed without a terminal operation such as `forEach()`, `collect()` or `reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said above, streams are lazy. That means that computation will not start without a terminate operation. You can use `forEach()` in your example. Replacing `peek` to `forEach` will start computation:

```
 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
 numbers
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x >= 5)
                .forEach(x-> System.out.print("x: " + x));
```

Answer (score 1):

`peek()` is an Intermediary operation which does not trigger the stream processing pipeline. You should have one and only one Terminal operation to trigger the stream processing pipeline. The stream is inherently lazy so that without one Terminal operation it wont be triggered. So add one terminal operator to your pipeline to see what you need. Here's one way of doing it.

```
long matchCount = numbers.stream().filter(x -> x >= 5)
    .peek(x -> System.out.println("peek at: " + x))
    .count();
```